# Spring Boot Application gets stuck on "Hikari-Pool-1 - Starting..."

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm trying to run Spring Boot application connected to PostgreSQL database. However, when it comes to Hikari connection pool initializing, it just gets stuck and nothing goes on. `HikariPool-1 - Starting...` appears in logs and then nothing happens.

Logs:

```
2018-07-09 15:32:48.475  INFO 21920 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@68999068: startup date [Mon Jul 09 15:32:48 ALMT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-09 15:32:48.736  INFO 21920 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b7bd026] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-07-09 15:32:49.207  INFO 21920 --- [           main] o.paperplane.todoapp.TodoappApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-09 15:32:49.217  INFO 21920 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1b410b60: startup date [Mon Jul 09 15:32:49 ALMT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@68999068
2018-07-09 15:32:49.763  INFO 21920 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Dbcp2; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Dbcp2.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]]
2018-07-09 15:32:50.046  INFO 21920 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=refresh; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]]
2018-07-09 15:32:50.212  INFO 21920 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=2203ab9b-5bb0-34f2-b496-2cbda1e334a2
2018-07-09 15:32:50.342  INFO 21920 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ff61cd29] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-09 15:32:50.380  INFO 21920 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$980f9563] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-09 15:32:50.389  INFO 21920 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-09 15:32:50.393  INFO 21920 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@309028af' of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-09 15:32:50.397  INFO 21920 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bce43815] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-09 15:32:50.404  INFO 21920 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-09 15:32:50.424  INFO 21920 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b7bd026] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-09 15:32:50.692  INFO 21920 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-07-09 15:32:50.710  INFO 21920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-07-09 15:32:50.710  INFO 21920 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-07-09 15:32:50.714  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;D:\node_js\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]
2018-07-09 15:32:50.817  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-09 15:32:50.817  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1600 ms
2018-07-09 15:32:51.784  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-09 15:32:51.785  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-09 15:32:51.785  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-09 15:32:51.785  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-09 15:32:51.785  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-07-09 15:32:51.785  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-09 15:32:51.786  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-09 15:32:51.786  INFO 21920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-07-09 15:32:51.885  INFO 21920 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
```

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.paperplane</groupId>
    <artifactId>todoapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>todoapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

My `apllication.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:55491/TodoAppDatabase
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=100
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_class=com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Hi, Did this error resolved. I am facing the same issue. Please reply

Comment: What are the effective versions of HikariCP and postgresql drivers?

Answer (score 4):

Normal postgresql port is **5432**, so I assume you also configured it to **55491**.

Double check this via your postgresql client using `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 55491 -d TodoAppDatabase -U admin`

At last you can put the HikariCP into DEBUG mode, so you can see what parameters its using.

If your properties file is really **apllication.properties** than this may also an issue because spring boot only picks up **application.properties** automatically.

Answer (score 2):

In my case spring.datasource.hikari.initializationFailTimeout was set to a really high value, 3600000 (1 hour). This, in it self, was not a malconfiguration but it hid the real problem as the app was hanging on startup.

Once that value was adjusted, I got a much more understandable stack trace which led me to the conclusion that in this case I couldn't use the default MariaDB driver configuration that I probably got through a jHipster.

A very wierd problem that I so far only has seen with MySQL8 and Ubuntu 20 on AWS EC2. Locally I run Ubuntu and MySQL8 via Docker without issues.

Answer (score 1):

try passing this parameter when you run your jar file:

`-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom`

Comment: Please justify your answer or add more information about what this process does.

Answer (score 1):

Making below change in application.properties should work fine:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<dbName>
```

Also make sure, you have Fixed Port Number box unchecked, in the pgAdmin configuration BOX, refer the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might not be able to connect to DB.
try restarting your DB instance and make sure it is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with a network connectivity. Make sure you can access your any configured servers if you got into this issue.

`telnet host 5432` will let you connect to see if a route exists to the DB server.

Answer (score 0):

in my case (windows 10), it took three steps:

1. stop the postgresql service running [image]
2. open command prompt as administrator and kill any service on port **5432**[image]
3. restart the postgresql service from services window.

and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved this by removing the `AUTO_SERVER=true` line in the *application.properties* file, so after removing that the application runs as usual.

Remove the `AUTO_SERVER=true` in `#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:... AUTO_SERVER=true`

*Whit this you loose the functionality to access the database from different sources like from the terminal, meaning you can't access the database from your terminal while your app is running (ie using the database)*

But if you need `AUTO_SERVER=true` then please restart your pc, and with it the database will restart which might solve your problem (*this is not a joke*).

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why **hikaripool-1** is taking a long time to start. One possibility is that there may be **high traffic on the network or server**, causing delays in processing requests.

Another possibility is that there may be technical issues with the software or hardware, which can also cause delays. It is recommended to **check the logs and error messages** for any clues about what might be causing the delay and to contact technical support for assistance if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, i have made only :

```
docker stop [ID_CONTAINER]
docker start [ID_CONTAINER]
```