# Spring :: Hikari Pool-1 starting... gets stuck on this line upon running the application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mariadb, spring-tool-suite, hikaricp

I have developed a spring boot application. previously it was working fine. now it is not working. it prints "HikariPool-1 - Starting..." and stucks here, does not move forward.

Below is my application.properties file for db configuration.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=pwd

spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=0
#spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=10000
#
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.jmx.default-domain=something
```

is there anything wrong in the above configuration which is causing this?

I tried with maxLifetime and leak-detection-threshold also but did not help so commented those in above configurations.

Comment: Try adding `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource` also are you using hibernate?

Comment: @user7294900 its giving error "Registered driver with driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource was not found, trying direct instantiation."

Comment: @Anjali - I think the port number might be an issue. Can you just try to connect to maria DB using above url & credentials using any database tool ? For example the way we have robomongo to mongodb, is there any specific tool available with you to test  maria DB with above data ?

Comment: @Rohit I am able to connect to database with same credentials using mysql workbench.

Comment: @Anjali - Are you having mysql driver also in classpath along with mariadb driver, this actually causes some issues.

Comment: Also check if you have allowed remote connections to maria db.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Application gets stuck on "Hikari-Pool-1 - Starting..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242938/spring-boot-application-gets-stuck-on-hikari-pool-1-starting)