# Spring Boot Application with mysql gets stuck on “Hikari-Pool-1 - Starting…”

Tags: mysql, spring

Similar to [Spring Boot Application gets stuck on “Hikari-Pool-1 - Starting…”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286104/spring-boot-application-gets-stuck-on-hikari-pool-1-starting) and [Spring Boot Application gets stuck on "Hikari-Pool-1 - Starting..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242938/spring-boot-application-gets-stuck-on-hikari-pool-1-starting) but in my case it was mysql.

I'm trying to run a Spring application. However, when it reaches `HikariPool-1 - Starting...` it gets stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the jdbc URL which was wrong.

I had `jdbc:mysql://myserver.com` instead of `jdbc:mysql:aurora://myserver.com`